# How to find Scrollbar middle point using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have one image and I'm scaling(*zooming*) based on some factor with in a viewport (`div`) which is of `fixed width` and `height`.

Currently image is completely fitting inside the `innerViewport`.
Once the image is zoomed, I need to `focus` the image to its **Middle point**.
To focus the image I'm planning to move the scroll bar to the middle of the viewport (`div`).

But I don't know how to solve this.

**Algorithm:**

1) retrieve `height` and `width` of the image

```
hI = image.width();
wI = image.height();
```

2) calculate the  zoom

```
hI = hI * 0.5
wI = wI * 0.5
```

3) set this back to image

```
image.setWidth(wI)
image.setHeight(hI)
```

4) set the same value to the image viewport

```
innerViewport.setWidth(wI)
innerViewport.setHeight(hI)
```

Till this point its working fine but to scrolling to its middle not working, as scrolls are currently in left top position.

**html**

```
<div viewport height=400 , width=400>
     <div innerViewport height= 999 width=999 overflow :scroll>
          <img height= 999 width=999>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the size of the viewport and the size of the image you can simple calculate the offset and use e.g. jQuery’s `scrollTop/scrollLeft` methods to set the scroll offset:

```
$viewport
  .scrollTop((imageHeight - viewportHeight) / 2)
  .scrollLeft((imageWidth - viewportWidth) / 2);
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/e6dK4/ — Just click the image.

Comment: This code only give the starting point of Scrollbar not mid point of scroll bar.

Comment: Yes im sure, My application only works in IE 8 ++ browers,Tried implementing this in IE found its not working. Sorry

Comment: The sample provided will scroll to the center _even_ on IE8: http://i.imgur.com/djqSUVd.png

Comment: i have tried the same fiddle in ie10 and found its not working but found one function to get proper height and width :                      h = viewport.getBoundingClientRect().height..etc

Comment: It’s rare that I have to break out two VMs to ‘prove my answer’, but here we go — IE10: http://i.imgur.com/3D1oqVK.png — Please note that already the previous example has been hosted on `jsbin` to remove any additional scripts which might cause conflicts out of my control.